# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/ReadSupport

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, connector

I am from Linkedin, we are having compatibility issue with spark-cdm-connector, to give a little context I have a cdm data in ADLS which I’m trying to read into Databricks 9.1 LTS Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12, I have installed com.microsoft.azure:spark-cdm-connector:0.19.1 and org.neo4j:neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12:4.1.2_for_spark_3, I tried multiple versions of neo4j-connector and spark-cdm-connector as well and its throwing this error
ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/ReadSupport.

Can you please provide proper version of spark-cdm-connector and neo4j-connector compatible for Databricks 9.1 LTS Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12 from these below available versions?
spark-cdm-connector versions available in Databricks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aies2.png)

neo4j-connector available in Databricks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxgVu.png)

ERROR context.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YybkZ.png)